# How do I connect to a remote VisualSVN server?

Tags: svn, phpstorm, remote-server, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I am trying to use VisualSVN and PhpStorm to connect to a remote VisualSVN Server. I have the IP address to the machine, and I have specified the path to the machine in both programs.

The paths I have tried:
svn://ip.ad.dr.ess/c:/Repositories 
svn+ssh://ip.ad.dr.ess/c:/Repositories

In Visual SVN, I receive **Cannot connect to WMI namespace. RPC server is unavailable. (0x800706BA)**

PhpStorm gives me **svn: E210002: There was a problem while connecting to ip.ad.dr.ess:22** when I use svn+ssh and **svn: E210003: connection refused by the server** when using svn://

Right now I am attempting to simply connect to the remote repositories, but the end goal is to be able to add repositories remotely.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`svn://ip.ad.dr.ess/c:/Repositories`

`svn+ssh://ip.ad.dr.ess/c:/Repositories`

These addresses are invalid. There should be no `c:` there. Moreover, VisualSVN Server does not server the repositories via `svn:` or `svn+ssh:` svnserve's protocols. It serves the repositories via **HTTP(S)**. You must double-check the correct URL. You can find it in VisualSVN Server Manager MMC console.

If you want to add the repositories remotely, you must be VisualSVN Server administrator (a member of *VisualSVN Server Admins* group on the server computer) and the server must be setup for remote administration per the article [KB25: Configuring Remote Administration](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00025/). Don't forger that you can also use PowerShell to administer the server remotely, see the page [PowerShell Scripting and Automation with VisualSVN Server](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/powershell/).

Comment: I found the https URL thanks to your advice. I am still receiving the same error from VisualSVN. I also should have mentioned that I am using VisualSVN Standard Edition. I am not sure if that plays a part in this.

Comment: @H.E. you can't use the feature https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/remote-admin/ with Standard Edition of the server. BTW, the error that you show means that the console was unable to contact the server -- firewall or wrong server hostname could be the reason.

Comment: Firewall was my original assumption, but your response helped me successfully connect to the repository from a remote computer on the network via https.